# How to remove trailing symbol for a constant in Rails initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, trim

How does one remove trailing character correctly in the following sentence if it's in `config/environment.rb` file.

```
KEY = ENV['KEY'].delete "\r"
```

It produces the following error:

```
undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

It works well in IRB, but not in environment.rb

**Solved**

Aptana Studio 3 stopped to load .bashrc after the latest update. Thanks to Mladen and Mark for help.

Comment: The error suggests that your `ENV['KEY']` is nil, check that first.

Comment: Hmm, can I access environment variables in the rails `environment.rb` file?

Comment: rather than putting "[solved]" in your title, you can answer your own question (but you have to wait some period of time before you can accept it).

Comment: @Mark: Sure! Just wanted to tell other experts, that the problem has been resolved.

Comment: if you accept an answer that will be shown anyway - the question indicator will turn gold in the question list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String#chop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000818) returns a copy of the string with the last character removed.  And it has a counterpart `String#chop!` which mutates the string as well.

However, your particular error (undefined method 'delete' for nil:NilClass) means that `ENV['KEY']` returned `nil`, which of course does not respond to the `delete` message.  You could try

```
KEY = ENV['KEY'].to_s.delete "\r"
```

to coerce it to a string.  `nil.to_s` returns the empty string, and `"".delete x` will still be `""`.  On the other hand if `ENV['KEY']` *does* correctly return a string, nothing different will happen than if you didn't include `to_s`.

Comment: Mark, thanks. I have updated my question - the problem is only in `environment.rb`

Comment: There's also `String#chomp`, which removes only newline chars.

Comment: It wasn't clear (to me) if he wanted to remove `"\r"` and keep `"\n"`.  `String#chomp` will of course remove both.